# Accessing Data from within angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having some trouble trying to figure this out, I'm trying to dynamically add user video data which contains a video URL. I'm trying to access the data from the component so I can interpolate it in my HTML. I'm not exactly sure how this works but Ive tried doing this..

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-video',
   templateUrl: './video.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./video.component.scss'],
   providers: [
      DashboardServiceProxy
   ]
})

export class VideoComponent implements OnInit {
   videos: UserVideoDto[] = [];
   // videos: Array<UserVideoDto> = []; 

constructor(
    private _dashboardService: DashboardServiceProxy
) {
    console.log(this.videos.VideoData); //data im trying to access
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getVideos();
  }

  getVideos() {
    this._dashboardService.getAllUserVideos().subscribe((result) => {
    this.videos = result;
    console.log(this.videos);
  });
  }

  }
```

at the moment im just trying to console.log the data but Im getting an error that says `[ts] Property 'videoData' does not exist on type 'UserVideoDto[]'`

**this is the UserVideoDto[] class**

```
public class UserVideoDto : EntityDto
  {
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public string VideoData { get; set; }

    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Series { get; set; }

    public String Subname { get; set; }

    public UserVideoDto()
    { }

  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you importing your service `DashboardServiceProxy`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide `UserVideoDto` interface or class? Basically you get a fail from typescript compiler since there is no `videoData` field on `UserVideoDto`.

For testing you could try this:

```
videos: Array<any> = []; // this should make TS error go away, but it won't solve issue you have
```

Also note that correct notation would be

```
videos: Array<UserVideoDto> = [];
```

Somewhere in your project you should have something like

```
interface UserVideoDto {
    ...
    public videoData: any;
    ...
}
```

or

```
class UserVideoDto {
    ...
    public videoData: any;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh... In the end it's just a typo
should be `console.log(this.videos.VideoData);`

Comment: Try to change this as well 
`videos: Array<UserVideoDto> = [];` You don't have Type  `UserVideoDto[]`. Only `UserVideoDto`

Comment: Tried to change that and Im still getting the same error

Comment: Can you try this just for debugging `videos: Array<any> = [];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160556/discussion-between-a61nn5-and-vuk-stankovic).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access VideoData in array, not instance of UserVideoDto.

It should be something like this.videos[x].VideoData

Answer (score 0):

As yfranz just mentioned you are trying to access a property that doesn't exist in your UserVideoDto[] which is an array.

Also your console.log is in the constructor, if you try to access the content there you won't get the data that you need because you are fetching the videos using the getVideos method inside ngOnInit. Any data manipulation for 'videos' should be done after you actually fetch the data inside the subscribe callback of _dashboardService.getAllUserVideos()